# Cron, python and saving to a file

Tags: linux, bash, cron, python

I've got a veeery simple script written in python that tests my internet connection na saves parsed data to a json file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess, json, os
from datetime import datetime

# run the bash script and parse results
def speedtest():
    result = subprocess.run(["/bin/speedtest-cli", "--simple"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="UTF-8").stdout
    # result = os.system("speedtest-cli --simple")
    download_str = result.find("Download: ") + 10
    download_speed = result[download_str:result.find(" Mbit/s", download_str)]
    upload_str = result.find("Upload: ") + 8
    upload_speed = result[upload_str:result.find(" Mbit/s", upload_str)]
    ping_str = result.find("Ping: ") + 6
    ping = result[ping_str:result.find(" ms", ping_str)]
    return download_speed, upload_speed, ping

def save_to_json(data):
    # load existing data to a dict
    existing_data = []
    with open("/home/trendkiller/development/python/py_speedtest/data.json") as fp:
        existing_data = json.load(fp)
   
    payload = {
        "date": datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
        "time": datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
        "download": data[0] + " Mbps",
        "upload": data[1] + " Mbps",
        "ping": data[2] + " ms"
    }
    
    existing_data.append(payload)

    # save to a json file
    with open("/home/trendkiller/development/python/py_speedtest/data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(existing_data, f, indent=4)

def main():
    test_result = speedtest()
    # save to a json_file
    save_to_json(test_result)
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It runs smoothly when I call it from terminal.
I would like to automate it so it can test my connection hourly.
For this I'm trying to use CRON and it works when I schedule it to run every minute (data is saved to data.json).
But when I try to run it hourly, data isn't passed to a json file.
Here's my crontab file:

```
@hourly /bin/python3 /home/trendkiller/python/py_speedtest/main.py
```

While looking at the `grep "CRON" /var/log/syslog`
there's nothing strange (to my knowledge):

```
Feb  5 08:00:01 home-lab CRON[119326]: (trendkiller) CMD (/bin/python3 /home/trendkiller/development/python/py_speedtest/main.py > /home/trendkiller/development/python/py_speedtest/log.txt)
Feb  5 08:00:04 home-lab CRON[119325]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb  5 08:17:01 home-lab CRON[119719]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  5 09:00:01 home-lab CRON[120590]: (trendkiller) CMD (/bin/python3 /home/trendkiller/development/python/py_speedtest/main.py > /home/trendkiller/development/python/py_speedtest/log.txt)
Feb  5 09:00:02 home-lab CRON[120589]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb  5 09:17:01 home-lab CRON[120798]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Any help would be very useful,
thanks in advance (and don't mind the clutterred code :P).

Comment: You can see in the log that your command produced some output (normal output or errors) but that this was discarded since you have not set up local email delivery.

Comment: Also note that the explicit interpreter that you're using to run your script seems to be different from what the script itself would use if you executed it directly.

Comment: Perhaps adding ">/tmp/speedtest.out 2>&1" to your cron entry would help in debugging the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick answer:

Write a script in `/etc/cron.hourly`.

`runpy` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/python3 /home/trendkiller/python/py_speedtest/main.py
```

Then make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/runpy
```

Test with `--report` or `--test`:

```
run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

[manpages.](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man8/run-parts.8.html)

Comment: You're still using a different interpreter from what's specified in the script itself, though.  Would it not be better to just make the scriptexecutable and schedule it directly?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make the program executable (`chmod u+x /home/trendkiller/python/py_speedtest/main.py`) and ensure it has a valid Python interpreter as its first line. The cron command would suggest `#!/bin/python3` but you've written `#!/usr/bin/python3`. Which is correct?

The CRON log output also suggests that the command you've shown us isn't actually the command you're running (one has a redirection of *stdout* to a log file, the other does not). Both are missing redirection of *stderr*.

You can either capture the output in the system logger:

1. Capture the output from your program, including errors written to *stderr*:

   ```
   @hourly /home/trendkiller/python/py_speedtest/main.py 2>&1 | logger -t py_speedtest -p user.info
   ```
2. Read the logfile (probably `grep py_speedtest /var/log/user.log`)

Or if you're not running a syslogger such as `rsyslog` you may prefer to just write the output to a file. But remember to truncate the file every so often, or replace it (use `>` instead of `>>`) each time your program runs rather than append to it.

1. Capture the output from your program, including errors written to *stderr*:

   ```
   @hourly ( date; /home/trendkiller/python/py_speedtest/main.py )>"$HOME/.py_speedtest.log" 2>&1
   ```
2. Read the logfile (for example `less "$HOME/.py_speedtest.log"`)

I would think it most likely that you're not in the directory you think you're in. *If* this is the case you can fix it by changing to your `$HOME` directory. For example,

```
@hourly cd && ( date; /home/trendkiller/python/py_speedtest/main.py )>".py_speedtest.log" 2>&1
```

(If your home directory is `/home/trendkiller` you can remove that from the command too: `python/py_speedtest/main.py`)